# Connection refused with GitLab CI Runner and GitLab CE in Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I've got problems trying to run both GitLab CE and the GitLab CI Runner in Docker containers.

This is how I run the GitLab CE container:

```
docker run --detach \
  --name gitlab \
  --hostname gitlab.local \
  --publish 80:80 \
  --restart always \
  --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://gitlab.local/';" \
  --volume ~/volumes/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume ~/volumes/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume ~/volumes/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce
```

Then **I can connect to GitLab without problems on the host** both through the locally bound interface — i.e. `http://localhost` — and the container IP — i.e. `http://gitlab.local` after adding e.g. `172.17.0.2   gitlab gitlab.local` on my hosts file).

The problems arise when I try to register a GitLab CI Runner container, through:

```
docker run --rm --tty --interactive \
    --name gitlab-runner-register \
    --add-host "gitlab.local:172.17.0.2" \
    --link=gitlab \
    --volume ~/volumes/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner \
    gitlab/gitlab-runner \
        register \
            --non-interactive \
            --executor "docker" \
            --docker-image alpine:3 \
            --url "http://gitlab.local/" \
            --registration-token "XXXXXXXXXXXX" \
            --description "docker-runner" \
            --tag-list "docker" \
            --run-untagged \
            --locked="false"
```

The errors I get are:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=XXXXXX status=couldn't execute POST against http://gitlab.local/api/v4/runners: Post http://gitlab.local/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:80: getsockopt: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Some help? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I've also tried to link a BusyBox to the `gitlab` container. Pinging it works like a charm, but `wget`ting it gives `Connection refused`:

```
$ docker run --rm --link=gitlab busybox ping -c 1 gitlab
PING gitlab (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms

--- gitlab ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.124/0.124/0.124 ms

$ docker run --rm --link=gitlab busybox wget http://gitlab
Connecting to gitlab (172.17.0.2:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.2): Connection refused
```

So networking is working fine and probably the "issue" is more related to the binding. As demonstration of this, I've tried to run a python http server in the `gitlab` container in order to retry the `wget` command and... it works:

```
$ docker run --rm --link=gitlab busybox wget http://gitlab:8000
Connecting to gitlab:8000 (172.17.0.2:8000)
index.html           100% |********************************|  1065  0:00:00 ETA
```

Comment: Changing the published port from `80` to `8000` of the `gitlab` container, and consequently the `--url` option from `http://gitlab.local/` to `http://gitlab.local:8000/` of the `gitlab-runner` container, it works. I don't understand if there are conflicts on `80`...